# Bootstrap 3 - non-responsive?

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I am using Bootstrap 3 in my WordPress theme.
Most of the site will make use of the responsive features, but for a few pages that host data visualizations I would like to force a fixed width.

**How would I set this non-responsivity up?**

(Would be nice if there was some sort of body class (.non-responsive) that could take precedence over the responsive features?)

Comment: Just override the class with your own style. Add a fixed width to the `.container` class if it has a `fixed-width` class as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a section in Bootstrap docs about disabling responsivness: 
http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#disable-responsive

> **Steps to disable responsive views**  
>   To disable responsive features,
>   follow these steps.
>
> 1. Remove (or just don't add) the viewport `<meta>` mentioned in the CSS
>      docs
> 2. Remove the `max-width` on the `.container` for all grid tiers with
>      `max-width: none !important;` and set a regular width like `width:
>      970px;`. Be sure that this comes after the default Bootstrap CSS. You
>      can optionally avoid the `!important` with media queries or some
>      selector-fu.
> 3. If using navbars, undo all the navbar collapsing and
>      expanding behavior (this is too much to show here, so peep the
>      example).
> 4. For grid layouts, make use of `.col-xs-*` classes in addition
>      to or in place of the medium/large ones. Don't worry, the extra-small
>      device grid scales up to all resolutions, so you're set there. You'll
>      still need Respond.js for IE8 (since our media queries are still there
>      and need to be picked up). This just disables the "mobile site" of
>      Bootstrap.

Answer (score 1):

What about this?

```
.non-responsive { width: 800px !important; }  //or whatever width you want it to be
```